# Question about implementation of binary search tree

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree, method-call

I am trying to learn the basics of data algorithms in C# and when implementing the below *binary search tree* add in process I get stuck at understanding the following: when calling the `tree1.add(20);` method, on the first iteration of the `while` loop the `current.Data` has the value of `50` and on the second iteration of the loop the value of the same `current.Data` changes to 40.
Why the value of the `current.Data` doesn't stuck at the value of 50 after the first iteration and what is the process by which the `current.Data` receives the value of 40?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BinarySearchTree
{
public class Node
{
    public int Data;
    public Node LeftChild;
    public Node RightChild;
}

public class BinarySearchTree
{
    public Node root;
    public BinarySearchTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }
    public void add(int data)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.Data = data;
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            Node current = root;
            Node parent;
            while (true)
            {
                parent = current;
                if (data < current.Data)
                {
                    current = current.LeftChild;
                    if (current == null)
                    {
                        parent.LeftChild = newNode;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.RightChild;
                    if (current == null)
                    {
                        parent.RightChild = newNode;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinarySearchTree tree1 = new BinarySearchTree();
        tree1.add(50);
        tree1.add(40);
        tree1.add(60);
        tree1.add(20);
        tree1.add(45);
        tree1.add(55);
        tree1.add(65);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: FYI you don't need the `parent` variable.  So instead of assigning the left or right to `current` just check if it's null and assign your `newNode` accordingly and if it isn't null then assign the child to `current`. Like this `if(current.LeftChild == null) { current.LeftChild = newNode; break;}else {current = current.LeftChild}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lays here:

```
while (true)
{
   parent = current;
   if (data < current.Data)
   {
      current = current.LeftChild; // THIS LINE
      if (current == null)
      {
         parent.LeftChild = newNode;
         break;
      }
   }
```

As you see, current is being revalued and now it is the left "child" of it self. After the first 3 `add` usages, the tree should look like this:

```
     50
    /  \
  40   60
```

So first iteration - current is 50, second iteration , it goes to the left(definition of a BST) and it becomes 40 . The next iteration current will contain `NULL` , (The left child of 40) and will be placed inside the BST.